# Miniupnp thinks my router doesn't support UPnP

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, upnp

I have a IP camera on my network that is truly plug n play. As soon as I plugged the Ethernet cable in, it was accessible from 'the outside', without me having to touch my router's configuration. So I know my router supports UPnP. I can also NMAP it an see that the UPnP server is listening on `5431`.

I'm trying to enable a temporary FTP server (changed to port 29 in this case) that I want a friend to be able to access. I installed miniupnp and ran the following command.

```
$ upnpc -l
upnpc : miniupnpc library test client. (c) 2005-2013 Thomas Bernard
Go to http://miniupnp.free.fr/ or http://miniupnp.tuxfamily.org/
for more information.
No IGD UPnP Device found on the network !
```

miniupnp is apparently having trouble finding my router, or thinks it's not enabling UPnP.

How can I troubleshoot this?

EDIT: I just managed to get a telnet session into my IP camera. Coincidently it is also running miniupnp, I ran the binary and it returned:

```
# ./upnpc-static -l    
upnpc : miniupnpc library test client. (c) 2006-2010 Thomas Bernard
Go to http://miniupnp.free.fr/ or http://miniupnp.tuxfamily.org/
for more information.
List of UPNP devices found on the network :
 desc: http://192.168.0.1:5431/dyndev/uuid:c03e0f29-4fec-ec4f-290f-3ec03e29ec0000
 st: urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:InternetGatewayDevice:1

Found valid IGD : http://192.168.0.1:5431/uuid:c03e0f29-4fec-ec4f-290f-3ec03e29ec0002/WANPPPConnection:1
Local LAN ip address : 192.168.0.30
Connection Type : IP_Routed
Status : Connected, uptime=127693s, LastConnectionError : 
  Time started : Wed Feb  4 01:06:15 2015
MaxBitRateDown : 20819000 bps   MaxBitRateUp 1209000 bps
ExternalIPAddress = 90.220.126.102
 0 TCP    80->192.168.0.30:80    'ipcam-h264' ''
 1 UDP 41441->192.168.0.4:41441 'Skype UDP at 192.168.0.4:41441 (2956)' ''
 2 TCP 41441->192.168.0.4:41441 'Skype TCP at 192.168.0.4:41441 (2956)' ''
GetGenericPortMappingEntry() returned 713 (SpecifiedArrayIndexInvalid)
```

So the same program on my IP camera is finding the IGD, wheras my laptop isn't.

Comment: It specifically says it didn’t find an **IGD type** UPnP device on the network. This is to be expected, UPnP firewall control is considered a security risk and as such disabled by default on modern devices. /edit: Oh yeah, and FTP is a bad choice, because it dynamically allocates ports for data connections.

Comment: @DanielB Good point about FTP, I'll use SSH but if you check my update above, the little embedded linux on my IP camera is having no problem finding the IGP with exactly the same command. I believe the problem definitely comes from my laptop, the router and the other device seem to have no problem communicating over UPnP protocol.

Comment: @user2018084 I'm having the same issue with miniupnpc: it doesn't find any UPnP devices. Did you discover a solution?